# C++ syntax for pointer and reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm doing a searching for swapping two nodes of linked list and found out a block of code as follow:

```
void swapNode(call * &head, call * &first, call * &second) {
    // swap values, assuming the payload is an int:
    int tempValue = first->value;
    first->value = second->value;
    second->value = tempValue;
}
```

My question is what the meaning for put the ampersand after asterisk?

Comment: As mentioned below that specifies a reference.  But it looks like you don't need it since you are not updating any of the parameters.

Comment: @AnonMail actually I don't use the head parameter, just swap the values in memory addresses first and second point to

Comment: Tested, no need for ampersand, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersand (&) here denotes `reference`. it is not the address operator.

This is the `C++` way of being able to change the value of a passed-in pointer because C/C++ pass parameters by value. In `C`, you would use a double pointer to achieve the same.

Comment: could you give me simpler examples about denote reference?

Comment: `&`  denotes `reference`, not that it is a `denote reference`.

Comment: so the `&` used for both `reference` and `address operator` ?

Comment: @PhiTruong If you use int var as a parameter to a function, any changes to var are local to the function (i.e. they are not seen outside the function).  If you use int & var as a parameter to a function any changes to var are seen inside and outside the function.